# Calendar link to different page views

Tags: list-view

I have several calendar views and I would like to point them to different page views I have created.

Is there a way of doing this? If so how would I go about doing this? It currently points to  `DispForm.aspx`

Please note SharePoint is fairly new to me.

I will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: So you got several calendar views and want them all to display in the same calendar? Or have you created multiple pages displaying the calendar items in different ways?

Comment: Hi Phil thank you for getting back to me, i have created 3 calendar views. And I have created 3 different display Forms. When you click on a calendar appointment in any of the calendar views it takes me to DispForm.aspx, but ideally i want it to go to the different Forms displays.

Comment: Hi Robert Lindgren, i tried the overlay feature by combining all the calendars, that only works for the calendar view, but when you click on the links it takes you to the same view details form, how would i make it go to the different forms?

Comment: b5ml, did you finally find a solution? I have the exact same problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Nathan sorry for the late reply, sorry i didnt find a solution. Have you found once since you added your post here?

Answer (score 0):

You could override default Calendar handler for displaying Event form as demonstrated below.

### How to override Calendar click handler for displaying Event form

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("body").on("dblclick click", ".ms-acal-item", function(e){
   e.stopPropagation(); 

  //extract default Event page url and generate new one
  var defaultEventPageUrl = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  var newEventPageUrl = defaultEventPageUrl.replace('Calendar','Team Calendar');

  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({title:"Meeting",url:newEventPageUrl});


});


</script>
```

> Note: jQuery library is loaded from CDN

Usage

- Add `Content Editor` web part on Calendar view page
- Insert the provided JavaScript code

Comment: Hi Vadim most appreciated I think your approach is heading the in the right direction. I tried to add the JS into the Content Editor (on the same page as the Calendar view page) but it seems to have not overridden the DispForm.aspx)
Is there somewhere i need to specify the new page i want it to link to?

I added:

$("body").on("dblclick click", ".ms-acal-item", function(e){
   e.stopPropagation(); 
   //set custom display calendar form URL 
   var displayUrl = '/mysandpit/Lists/CalendarTest/DispForm.aspx?ID=1';

   SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({title:"Meeting",url:displayUrl });

});

Comment: Hi, please make sure to wrap the JS code inside the script tag:  <script>...</script>

Comment: Hi Vadim, if its working for you, i must be obviously doing something wrong somewhere... this is it wrapped... <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

$("body").on("dblclick click", ".ms-acal-item", function(e){
   e.stopPropagation(); 
   //set custom display calendar form URL 
   var displayUrl = '/mysandpit/Lists/CalendarTest/DispForm.aspx?ID=1';

   SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({title:"Meeting",url:displayUrl });

});
</script>


Is the first url path.. showing the final destination? Or do I need to add this?

Comment: One more question, which version of SharePoint are you using? Probably it should be the first question:)

Comment: Its Sharepoint 2010 Vadim... The Content Editor on this version doesn't always need the JS opening and closing tags. Nonthe less i have tried both options.

Comment: The answer has been updated. Since there is a dependency to jQuery library, script reference has been included to load library from CDN. After inserting the specified code into CEWP, please make sure to refresh the browser cache

Comment: Hi Vadim, I am sorry about this, its all new to me, where do i find this CDN? I have refreshed the cache on the browser and also loaded into a different Internet browser, I don’t seem to see a change.

Comment: it's all right, could you please just try once again to include the whole code from the updated answer into CEWP? you dont need to worry about CDN

Comment: Hi Vadim i added the whole snippet as advised... with the path /mysandpit/Lists/CalendarTest/DispForm1.aspx?ID=1 it still seems to have not made a change, It still points to DispForm1.aspx. I am sorry about this.

Comment: Hi Vadim I added to snippet directly into the Content Editor (via HTML Source)And removed the link to the .js file under Site Assets. This has made a little change, however, the original modal box (DispForm.aspx) still appears in the background and in the foreground an additional modal box appears, saying ‘Meeting’ along the bar and within the content area it says '404 NOT FOUND'. The page is there on the system and is called: Clinician-personal-calendar-View.aspx The path I am entering is: '/mysandpit/Lists/CalendarTest/Clinician-personal-calendar-View.aspx?ID=1'

Comment: Hi Vadim, any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Hi Vadim, Sorry to bother you again, I am not sure if you had the chance to look at this? It’s the last hurdle I have before I complete the calendar feature. Basically the Modal box was appearing but no content in it. (with the original modal box sitting in the background) Do you know why this?

Comment: I have managed to get the modal working with the correct page, but how do I make this dynamic? So it shows the correct record when clicking on the Calendar link… 
Finally in the background it’s still showing the dispForm.aspx page… it looks like it is not overridden the original form.

Comment: That's great, congratulations! But I don't know yet why it display the original display form in your case. Regarding the dynamic url, i guess you need to pass list item id, right?

Comment: Thank you, Yes, i need to pass the correct item, how would i do that? 
Not sure why its showing two modal boxes, I have tested it in IE7, IE8, Chrome and Firefox. Isnt there a way of getting rid of it?

Comment: Hi Vadim
This doesn't work when you click on the hyperlink in the calendar. (Because it brings up the default form up in the background)
But if you click in the box area for that date (not hyperlink) (it ONLY brings up the specified Form view.) This is fine.
So i am thinking; We can have a work-around.
Is there away of disabling the hyperlink ie. removing the hyperlink itself?

I am guess if this hyperlink is removed. Then users would only be able click on box area which would in turn load the new Form view (and not the default calendar)

Will appreciate your help on this as its the last part.

Comment: Hi, that's really good that you've found the root cause of showing default form.  I will check that today and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks Vadim, most appreciated, it’s the last part of the project. And I feel I am close. I just hope this new approach will work. I can then use this for all the calendars.

Comment: Any luck with this Vadim?

Comment: Hi Vadim I have managed to disable the link... now one last thing... i need to make the following dynamic (from static): 

var displayUrl = '/project/Lists/Team Calendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=1'; //static link for testing purposes so it goes to the correct item records. 

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, regarding dynamic event page url, you could extract the default event page url and then replace list url. The answer has been updated

Comment: Thanks Vadim where do i put the URL for the calendar.. sorry JavaScript is new to me...

Comment: Np, you could just use the trick i used in the answer. For example if your original Calendar diaplay page url is located here: https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Lists/Calendar/DispForm.aspx and you would like to open form at: https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Lists/Team Calendar/DispForm.aspx, then you could just replace the part of url as I did in the answer

Comment: Also please note the event Id will be preserved in that case, it also means you actually don't need to extract Id parameter

Comment: Hi Vadim by copy and pasting your answer (the snippet of code) into the Contnet Editor, it doesnt open the Modeal box at all. So what exactly do i need to do?

Comment: Hm, just checked and works for me..  my suggestion is replace part of the url as I explained earlier

Comment: To be fair, I've spent too much time on this question so far and not even a single up-vote..

Comment: I wish i could Vadim id give you more than 1, but Vote Up requires 15 reputation. 

So Vadmin i replace this: "newEventPageUrl" with 'Clinician-Personal-Calendar.aspx'?

Comment: No worries, Okey, i propose the following way, if you will tell me url of your current(default) event page, and the url of the page where would like to be opened when the user clicks the event, i could update my answer accordingly.
For example:
<web>/Lists/Calendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=<ItemId> -> <web>/Lists/Calendar/CustomForm.aspx?ID=<ItemId> and I will update the answer

Comment: Hi Vadmin...

This is where the calendar view sits: http://pen/sites/mysandpit/Lists/CalendarTest/Clinician-Personal-Calendar.aspx

and this is the destination page i would like it to go to:

http://pen/sites/mysandpit/Lists/CalendarTest/Clinician-personal-calendar-View.aspx

The default desitnation page: http://pen/sites/mysandpit/Lists/CalendarTest/DispForm.aspx

Regards

Comment: Any ideas Vadim?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating three custom Event content types and associating them with a calendar?  Each content type can be customized as needed (e.g. columns and display forms).  As long as the appropriate content type is used to create new items, when an item link is clicked from the calendar the desired display form will open.   Additionally, the overlay feature can be used in a calendar list utilizing multiple content types if a common column is used across all three content types.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late in answering but I found this solution. Opening the calendar view in Sharepoint designer 2013, I used Ctrl+F to find DispForm.aspx and in that line I changed it to refer to 
    /Item/editifs.aspx?&DefaultView=Disp&" 
Here the Disp is referencing to my Infopath Form View, which you may even change. Hope this helps.